# Yii2 - Combining data from 2 tables with a 3 table to compair it with

Tags: database, yii2

Im working on getting data from a database, in this case from 3 tables, 'product' is used to check if the product is deleted or enabled, if the product is not deleted and is enabled than the 'product_translation' is used to get the language , translation & product_id (this is used to group the data with ArrayHelper::index)  this goes well(see code below), but I now need to get data from a third table (in this case a category -> category_translation) which has a translation field which we want to to add to the data output, this field must match  the following ways the category_id, attribute & language fields must match all. I hope that somebody understands this.

Im new to yii2 so I still are figuring out how to use this all.

```
   ----------------------------------------------
   | product                                    |
   ----------------------------------------------
   | id | is_deleted | is_enabeld | category_id |
   ----------------------------------------------

   ---------------------------------------------------
   | product_translation                             |
   ---------------------------------------------------
   | product_id | attribute | language | translation |
   ---------------------------------------------------

   ----------------------------------------------------
   | category_translation                             |
   ----------------------------------------------------
   | category_id | attribute | language | translation |                                   
   ----------------------------------------------------
```

Used query until now:

```
  $query = new Query;

    $slugs = $query->select('pt.language , pt.translation , pt.product_id , p.category_id , ct.translation as category')
                   ->from(['pt' => 'product_translation'])
                   ->leftJoin(['p' => 'product'] , 'p.id = pt.product_id')
                   ->leftJoin(['ct' => 'category_translation'] , 'ct.category_id = p.category_id')
                   ->where(['p.is_deleted' => 0,
                            'p.is_enabled' => 1,
                            'pt.attribute'  => 'slug',
                            'ct.attribute'  => 'slug'

                            // when adding this it will not return any data at all
                            // when not adding this it will return double/wrong data
                           'ct.language' => 'pt.language'

                           ])
                   ->all();

 // Group values by id.
 $results = ArrayHelper::index( $slugs , null , 'product_id' );
```

Comment: when you say **category_id, attribute & language fields must match all** do you mean you want to join the 3rd table based on these 3 fields? where `attribute` and `language` should be matched in `product_transalation` and `category_id` in `product` table.

Comment: yes thats correct(ive updated the code that have have build untill now)

Comment: can you replace the `->createCommand()->rawSql;` with `->all();` and paste the result `sql` in the original post .

Comment: and you can remove one statement from these two `'pt.attribute'  => 'slug','ct.attribute'  => 'slug'`